# How to traverse an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to create a tree structure using tree array, but I'm unable to traverse the array correctly. I used the following code:

```
    function fnAppend(param) {
       var tree= [ {
                    "name": "A","children": [
                      {
                        "name": "A1","children": [
                          {
                            "name": "A2","children": []
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "A3","children": []
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "B1","children": [
                          {
                            "name": "B2","children": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "B","children": []
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "C","children": [
                      {
                        "name": "C1","children": [
                          {
                            "name": "C2","children": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ];
       for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
          console.log("Mother : "+tree[i].name);
          var childArray = tree[i].children;
          for(var j = 0; j < childArray.length; j++){
             console.log("Child :"+childArray[j].name);
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nina Scholz please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a recursion and hand over the parent name.

```js
const iter = parent => ({ name, children }) => {
    console.log('parent', parent, 'name', name);
    if (children.length) children.forEach(iter(name));
};

var tree = [{ name: "A", children: [{ name: "A1", children: [{ name: "A2", children: [] }, { name: "A3", children: [] }] }, { name: "B1", children: [{ name: "B2", children: [] }] }] }, { name: "B", children: [] }, { name: "C", children: [{ name: "C1", children: [{ name: "C2", children: [] }] }] }];

tree.forEach(iter());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursion method will work.

```
function children(list){
   for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
     var name = list[i].name;
     console.log(name);

     if(list[i].children != undefined){
        children(list[i].children);
     }
   }
}
```

What it does is: it loops the passed level of array then checks if any of the objects have children if so it calls itself and does that again until no children are found then it continues with next object.

Here's a full [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4xg8y01/).

Answer (score 0):

This is where you need a recursion function.

```js
function traverse(arr) {
  for (const branch of arr) {
    console.log('Mother:', branch.name);


    if (Array.isArray(branch.children) && branch.children.length > 0) {
      console.log('Children:', branch.children.map(i => i.name).join(', '));
      traverse(branch.children);
    }
  }
}

traverse(tree);
```